# What is the GCP CloudSQL HA replication solution used for Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql, high-availability

Based on the descriptions it seems that for the Highly Available Postgresql, the [File System (Block Device) Replication](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/different-replication-solutions.html) is used. However it is not officially confirmed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I means the automatic failover if a zone goes down in a region and an automatic switch to another zone, in the same region, is documented [here](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/high-availability)

The trick is the usage of a regional persistent disk. In fact, it's a low layer disk synchronisation, guaranteed by Google Cloud that allow that synchronisation. Not a postgreSQL feature.

Comment: I assume this is the right answer, since none from GCP answered officially.